# Powershell arguments by reference

Tags: powershell, pass-by-reference

My understanding is that a complex object like a hash table is always passed by reference, while simple objects like strings or booleans are passed by value. I have been using this "fact" to do dependency injection with functions, and it has seemed to work until I need to pass the dependency on to a further function.
So I decided to do a simplified test to see where things are going wrong. And now even the dependency injection seems not to work. In this code, my expectation was that since I initially define `$state` as the return value from Primary in it's "Initialize" mode, I could then simply pass that on to further functions by reference, and when looking at `$state` at completion I would see all four times, as well as the id.

```
function Primary {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ParameterSetName = 'initialize')]
            [String]$id,
        
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ParameterSetName = 'process')]
            [Hashtable]$state
    )

    if ($id) {
        Write-Host 'initialize Primary'
        $primary = [Ordered]@{}
        $primary.Add('id', $id)
        $primary.Add('primaryInit', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
        Secondary -state:$primary -init
    } else {
        Write-Host 'process Primary'
        $primary = $true
        $state.Add('primaryProcess', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
        Secondary -state:$state
    }

    return $primary
}

function Secondary {
    param (
        [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'initialize')]
            [Switch]$init,
        
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [Hashtable]$state
    )

    if ($init) {
        Write-Host 'initialize Secondary'
        $state.Add('secondaryInit', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
    } else {
        Write-Host 'process Secondary'
        $state.Add('secondaryProcess', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
    }
}

CLS
$state = Primary -id:'Test'
Primary -state:$state

CLS
foreach ($key in $state.Keys) {
    Write-Host "$key $($state.$key)"
}
Write-Host
```

No such luck, I only see the primaryInit time. And yet, in my much more complex program, it seems as if I AM getting `$state` passed by reference. So, I wonder what is different in this very simple example, that it's not behaving as intended? Or am I misunderstanding what is happening, and some more in my production code I am creating a behavior that I misunderstand to be innate behavior?
I also tried an even more simplified version, to remove the part calling functions from within functions.

```
function ByReference {
    param (
        [Hashtable]$state
    )

    $state.Add('now', (Get-Date))
}

$state = [Ordered]@{
    id = 'test'
}

ByReference $state

foreach ($key in $state.Keys) {
    Write-Host "$key $($state.$key)"
}
```

This also shows `$state` being passed by Value, such that the changes aren't seen when looking at the variable in Main.

EDIT: Based on @Daniel 's link, I revised to

```
function Primary {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ParameterSetName = 'initialize')]
            [String]$id,
        
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ParameterSetName = 'process')]
            [Ref]$state
    )

    if ($id) {
        Write-Host 'initialize Primary'
        $primary = [Ordered]@{}
        $primary.Add('id', $id)
        $primary.Add('primaryInit', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
        Secondary -state:$primary -init
    } else {
        Write-Host 'process Primary'
        $primary = $state
        $state.Add('primaryProcess', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
        Secondary -state:$state
    }

    return $primary
}

function Secondary {
    param (
        [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'initialize')]
            [Switch]$init,
        
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [Ref]$state
    )

    if ($init) {
        Write-Host 'initialize Secondary'
        $state.Add('secondaryInit', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
    } else {
        Write-Host 'process Secondary'
        $state.Add('secondaryProcess', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
    }
}

CLS
$state = Primary -id:'Test'
Primary -state:$state

CLS
foreach ($key in $state.Keys) {
    Write-Host "$key $($state.$key)"
}
Write-Host
```

And this is still not showing anything but the very first time. That said, I can get this to work.

```
Function Test($data)
{
    $data.Test = "New Text"
}

$var = @{}
Test -data $var
$var
```

Which got me thinking maybe this only works if you aren't using a `param()` block. So I tried removing the param block and using `function Primary ([String]$id, [Ref]$state) {}`. Still no joy.

The other thing I notice is that all the examples create the variable in main. I am creating the variable in the init mode of my method. Could it be that the variable needs to be global or script scope? I tried using scope modifiers when initially defining $primary but thiat isn't working either.

EDIT 2: So it seems the key is you must not type the byRef argument.
So this works.

```
function Test-Primary {
    param (
        [String]$id,
        $state = [Ordered]@{}
    )

    if ($id) {
        Write-Host 'initialize Primary'
        $state.Add('id', $id)
        $state.Add('primaryInit', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
        Test-Secondary -state:$state -init
        return $state
    } else {
        Write-Host 'process Primary'
        $state.Add('primaryProcess', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
        Test-Secondary -state:$state
    }
}

function Test-Secondary {
    param (
        [Switch]$init,
        $state
    )

    if ($init) {
        Write-Host 'initialize Secondary'
        $state.Add('secondaryInit', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
    } else {
        Write-Host 'process Secondary'
        $state.Add('secondaryProcess', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
    }
}

CLS

$state = Test-Primary -id:'Test'
Test-Primary -state:$state

CLS
foreach ($key in $state.Keys) {
    Write-Host "$key $($state.$key)"
}
Write-Host
```

A little odd, as I would wish that you could either specifically type the parameter, so ensure you don't change type, but I guess that's just another reason to start using Classes. Functions are "sloppy" because they are intended for down and dirty stuff I guess.

EDIT: OK, progress, but it seems I am still trying to do something odd. I have come to the conclusion that, when doing these multi-"mode" functions where one mode returns a value and the other mode uses a passed by reference variable, you need a different name for the return value. Add to that I need for `[Ref]` both when calling the function and declaring the variable in the function. I then assumed that I could use `[Ref]` even with a hash table, as a way to remind myself that this is a by reference value. And then the need for `.Value` to actually deal with the variable got me to this.

```
function Test-Primary {
    param (
        [String]$id,
        [Ref]$state
    )

    if ($id) {
        Write-Host 'initialize Primary'
        $testPrimary = [Ordered]@{}
        $testPrimary.Add('id', $id)
        $testPrimary.Add('primaryInit', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
        Test-Secondary -state:([Ref]$testPrimary) -init
        return $testPrimary
    } else {
        Write-Host 'process Primary'
        $state.Value.Add('primaryProcess', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
        Test-Secondary -state:$state
    }
}

function Test-Secondary {
    param (
        [Switch]$init,
        [Ref]$state
    )

    if ($init) {
        Write-Host 'initialize Secondary'
        $state.Value.Add('secondaryInit', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
    } else {
        Write-Host 'process Secondary'
        $state.Value.Add('secondaryProcess', (Get-Date))
        Start-Sleep -s:(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
    }
}

CLS

$state = Test-Primary -id:'Test'
Test-Primary -state:([Ref]$state)

CLS
foreach ($key in $state.Keys) {
    Write-Host "$key $($state.$key)"
}
Write-Host
```

Comment: Take a look here [Writing functions to accept reference parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-7.1#writing-functions-to-accept-reference-parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you figured out hash tables don't need to be passed by reference to change its properties. But to show you how `[Ref]` actually works, take a look at the following example:

```
function Test-RefParameter
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Ref] $Output
    )

    $Output.Value = "output from test"
}


$testVar = "before test"
Write-Information "Current value: '$testVar'" -InformationAction Continue

Test-RefParameter -Output ([Ref]$testVar)

Write-Information "Current value: '$testVar'" -InformationAction Continue
```

Which displays:

```
Current value: 'before test'
Current value: 'output from test'
```

So the key is to use `.Value` when assigning the value to the `[Ref]` parameter

Comment: Aha, `[Ref]` at both ends, and `.Value` where the missing bits!